# Linux AD controller for Linux workstation

Tags: linux, active-directory

I want to make an Linux Active Directory and I want to use it for Linux devices.
Something like this:

I want all my Linux devices to be in the same Domain Server, I want to be able to deploy files on Linux workstations, change policies, system settings etc.

Is this possible, if yes with which Linux distribution for server and for workstations.

Comment: Look on PAM & NIS/YP etc....

Comment: Thank you i will try and see if i can understand how to use what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Univention Corporate Server (UCS) is something like Microsoft active directory but is for Linux devices. There are free or paid (business) licenses for UCS and it can handle clients of Linux or non-linux OS. I think this is what you are after.
https://www.univention.com/